# SQL: using clause with "ORDER BY"

Tags: mysql, filter, clause

I have a list of orders in a SQL table, and for each order I have a ship-to country code.

example:

```
order     country_code
X00145    GB
X00178    FR
D55454    AL
E54566    GB
F59565    IE
O84849    ES
K54545    US
N61465    GB
W65478    GB
```

I am trying to sort the output so orders that are *not* going to country_code GB are returned first, alphabetically , and then have the GB orders come last (like after IE and US in my example above).

Using "ORDER BY" only lets me filter with ASC or DESC. Is there a way to use a clause along with "ORDER BY"? (I guess not because I could not find anything online)?

Comment: Many thanks all for all your replies. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL you could do

```
select * from your_table
order by country_code = 'GB', 
         country_code,
         `order`
```

or generally

```
select * from your_table
order by case when country_code <> 'GB' then 1 else 2 end, 
         country_code,
         `order`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by field()`

```
select * from table_name
order by field(country_code,'GB') desc,country_code
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9b8a/1)**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from yourtable where  country_code != 'GB' order by country_code

Union 

select * from yourtable where  country_code = 'GB'
```